# Change property value while converting from XML to JSON

Tags: c#, json.net

In a project I'm getting some data from DB using TSQL FOR XML. In all tables the minimun value for Date fields is set to `01/01/1900`.

That's because null values are not permitted as an internal politic that cannot be changed.

With the xml result I need to convert it to JSON and serialize it to a client.

For doing so I'm using:

```
string jSonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDoc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);
```

Good; now I need to convert each `01/01/1900` date to `DateTime.MinValue` (01/01/0001) while converting into JSON; how can I handle this?

Comment: It sounds like a bad design in the database to start with - those date columns should be null to represent no date rather than 01/01/1900 - I'd start by correcting that.

Comment: @TrevorPilley I know, but null values are not permitted as an internal politic that cannot be changed. Added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** - Modified code to work for any node/attribute that has value `01/01/1900`.

I would process XML document before conversion to JSON. Here is LinqPad example for how to do it if your date value is node or attribute value. Since I don't know your XML data structure bare with simplistic example:

```
void Main()
{
    // IF IT IS NODE VALUE
    var xml = @"<data>
        <objectA>
            <dateValueA>01/01/1900</dateValueA>
            <dateValueB>01/01/1971</dateValueB>
        </objectA>
        <objectB>
            <dateValueA>01/01/2002</dateValueA>
            <dateValueB>01/01/1900</dateValueB>
            <dateValueZ>01/01/2011</dateValueZ>
        </objectB>
        <objectC>
            <dateValueA>01/01/1910</dateValueA>
            <dateValueB>01/01/2012</dateValueB>
            <dateValueC>01/01/1900</dateValueC>
        </objectC>
    </data>";

    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

    var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//*[text()='01/01/1900']");
    foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        node.InnerText = "01/01/0001";
    }

    string jSonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDoc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);

    "// IF IT IS NODE VALUE - RESULTS".Dump();
    jSonString.Dump();

    // IF IT IS ATTRIBUTE VALUE
    var xmlAttr = @"<data>
        <objectA dateValueA='01/01/1900' dateValueB='01/01/1900' dateValueC='01/01/2011' />
        <objectB dateValueB='01/01/2011' someOtherDate='01/01/1900' />
        <objectC dateValueC='01/01/1900' dontChangeThisDate='05/04/1923' />
    </data>";

    var xmlDocAttr = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlAttr);

    var nodesAttr = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//*[@*='01/01/1900']");
    for(var i=0; i < nodesAttr.Count; i++)
    {
        foreach(XmlAttribute attrib in nodesAttr[i].Attributes)
        {
            if (attrib.Value == "01/01/1900")
            {
                attrib.Value = "01/01/0001";
            }
        }
    }

    string jSonStringAttr = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDoc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);

    "// IF IT IS ATTRIBUTE VALUE - RESULTS".Dump();
    jSonStringAttr.Dump();

}
```

And results:

```
// IF IT IS NODE VALUE - RESULTS
{"objectA":{"dateValueA":"01/01/0001","dateValueB":"01/01/1971"},"objectB":{"dateValueA":"01/01/2002","dateValueB":"01/01/0001","dateValueZ":"01/01/2011"},"objectC":{"dateValueA":"01/01/1910","dateValueB":"01/01/2012","dateValueC":"01/01/0001"}}

// IF IT IS ATTRIBUTE VALUE - RESULTS
{"objectA":{"@dateValueA":"01/01/0001","@dateValueB":"01/01/0001","@dateValueC":"01/01/2011"},"objectB":{"@dateValueB":"01/01/2011","@someOtherDate":"01/01/0001"},"objectC":{"@dateValueC":"01/01/0001","@dontChangeThisDate":"05/04/1923"}}
```

Would that work for you?

Comment: I can't handle the problem in this way; my function must be generic (used for some SP) and I can't know programmatically the name of DateTime columns

Comment: @IrvinDominin I updated code to work with any node or attribute name that has value `01/01/1900`. Would that work?

Comment: The only side effect is that a string containing that value will be converted too. And I'm a bit afraid that running a regex on a mid length xml can be cost expensive

Comment: @IrvinDominin That is not correct. The example above will not change value inside of string, it is exact match for value of the node or attribute. I am also not sure about your concern 'cost expensive'. You will have to scan full document to find those values that need to be replaced. I would be curious to see what you end up doing, because this is a good question, something I would like to know for the future use.

Comment: At the end I'm using this solution, on my test is not cost expensive. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you control the T-SQL, you could try replacing the value in the query:

```
CASE   
    WHEN [DateWhichCantBeNull] = '1900-01-01'
        THEN '0001-01-01'
    ELSE [DateWhichCantBeNull]
END AS "DateWhichCantBeNull"
```

You may need to cast that as `DateTime2` if it still needs to be a real date for the serialisation to work correctly.

Comment: This was my first thought, but the SP I'm using cannot be changed. I know this structure have some limits...